# New network interface created after reboot - OEL 6

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, network-interface

We do not remember the setting apply via network manager applet -Redhat6 -
but after each reboot of the virtual machine, new network interface appear in network manager with no ip address no mac.
This mean after each reboot setting must be apply to the new network interface on networkmanager applet
[image]

The ip address must be manual and the name should be System eth0

The virtualizer is Xen
The Virtual machine Oracle Enterprise Linux 6

Is it possible to fix this setting permanent ???

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

When you set a static ip address for a connection, you are creating a connection method for network manager to use. This is not a new interface rather a method of using the interface "eth0". Though you have a static ip address assigned to it, DHCP is still an option. This I believe is done out of convenience. Take the scenario that you often setup a temporary link to your friends laptop due to a lack of wifi. Now you can leave that profile there and switch back to DHCP for your normal connection without having to reconfigure the interface every time. (Bad Example but it emphasizes my point)

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, we would like to use System eth0 (method or profile) by default. Is it possible ? cause after each restart of the vm a new profile is setup and selected ???

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that this is a Xen virtual machine.

Apparently the virtualization host does not assign persistent MAC addresses to the virtual NICs. Every time the VM is powered on, the host may assign a new MAC address for its virtual NIC. And as the MAC address changes, OEL 6 will "think" the NIC is not the same as before.

The instructions for optimizing the VM's operating system for virtualization should have included the steps to avoid this problem. However, the generic way to do this for OEL/RHEL 6.x is:

1.) Create an empty file `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules`. This will override the corresponding file in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` and so will disable `udev`'s MAC address memory function:

```
touch /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
```

2.) Delete the existing record of MAC addresses previously seen by udev:

```
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

3.) Delete any `HWADDR=` lines from any existing network configuration files:

```
sed -i -e '/^HWADDR=/d' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*
```

4.) Reboot the VM. Now it should accept the first NIC as `eth0`, the second as `eth1` etc. and ignore any future MAC address changes on them.